# Filtering and editing the list data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following data from a service. I have to filter it on some conditions.

```
Train    Manufacturer        Model          Type      Name           EnableQuery

Train2   RSS                 Model123       City      "C-124"           1

Train2   ABC                 Iron-Bar       Village   "H-78"            0 

Train2   AHAJ-Manufacturer   Steel-123      City      "HJ-TY"           0

Train2   ABC                 AmazeModel     City      "SD-12"           1

Train1   JK                  Platinum-123   City      "HJK-2728"        1
```

When the **"Train"** field is repeated more than once I have a condition which goes like this:

I have to select **"Type"** and **"Name"** where Model is **"Steel-123"** , yes this is a hardcoded value and if it's not found leave it blank.I have to select **"Manufacturer"** ,**"Model"** where **"Model"** is not equal to "Steel-123" , take the first value else blank.

I have to add the **"EnableQuery"** value .

**My expected output is:**

```
Train    Manufacturer        Model          Type      Name           EnableQuery

Train2   RSS                 Model123       City      "HJ-TY"           2

Train1   JK                  Platinum-123   City      "HJK-2728"        1
```

I am getting the original input from a service which I dont have control on.

```
public class Train
{
        public string Train { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Train> lstTr = //from service;
```

I tried to implement Group by in LINQ but it would not solve my purpose , because there are 3 different conditions even in group by .

How do I select and simultaneously edit the rows with same column in C#? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renamed your `Train` class to `TrainRecord`, since it contains a property called `Train`, which is illegal.

```
static IEnumerable<TrainRecord> FunnyTrainAggregator(IEnumerable<TrainRecord> trains)
{
    const string steel123Name = "Steel-123";

    return trains
        .GroupBy(t => t.Train, (key, values) =>
        {
            var trainsInGroup = values.ToList();
            TrainRecord result;
            if (trainsInGroup.Count > 1)
            {
                var steel = trainsInGroup.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == steel123Name);
                var nonsteel = trainsInGroup.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name != steel123Name);
                result = new TrainRecord
                {
                    Train = key,
                    Manufacturer = nonsteel?.Manufacturer,
                    Model = nonsteel?.Model,
                    Type = steel?.Type,
                    Name = steel?.Name,
                    EnableQuery = trainsInGroup.Sum(t => t.EnableQuery)
               };
            }
            else
                result = trainsInGroup[0];
            return result;
        });
}
```